# Question about the inverse of a logical statement.

Tags: logic

Suppose I have the statement if $a | b$, then $a \nmid c$ for any $c \neq b$. I know that taking the inverse of a logical statement is negating both the antecedent and consequent, while maintaining the order in which they appear. Given a quantified statement like the one above, is the inverse equivalent to, if $a \nmid b$, then $a | c$ for some $c \neq b$? My guess is that this is correct, but I wanted to make sure that the inverse is not given by, if $a \nmid b$, then $a | c$ for all $c \neq b$.

Comment: If the original statement is $P\implies Q$, the contrapositive is the statement $\neg Q\implies \neg P$ and is logically equivalent to the original statement.  On the other hand, the inverse statement is $\neg P\implies \neg Q$ which is logically equivalent to the converse $Q\implies P$ and is not logically equivalent to the original statement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have it right! The negatation of a statement of the form "for all $x$, {something}" is "there exists $x$ such that (negation of {something})".

As a side note, the more common term for this is "converse", not "inverse". Since every implication is equivalent to its contrapositive, the converse implication of $P \implies Q$, which you defined as $\lnot P \implies \lnot Q$, is equivalent to $Q \implies P$. This is a more helpful way for me to think about converse implications.

Comment: Thank you! I figured that was the case.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the converse would hold for all P and Q. So it's not the same thing as the inverse defined in this question.

Comment: What do you mean by "for all P and Q"? P and Q represent arbitrary propositions in my post.